# newbie in c and issue with integers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  int x =10, y =20, b = 500;
  int z = x*y;
  int f = z/b;

  // insert code here...
  printf("x is:%d, y is:%d, b is %d\n",x,y,b);
  printf("x times y is: %d\n",z);
  printf("z divided by b is: %d\n",f);
  return 0;
}
```

on print out f = 0.  Why?

Comment: Int means integer. Is there some digits after the dot with integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `int` type is an integer, which holds values that you can use to count (1, 2, 3...). It does not handle anything past a decimal point.

If I were to assign a value with anything past the decimal to an `int`, all the numbers on the right-hand side of the decimal would be truncated:

```
int v = 3.14159
```

would leave me with a value of `3` for `v`, because the integer can't store the .14159.

Your value of 200/500 is 0.4, which is truncated to 0 when it is assigned to the `int f`.

In order to store decimal values, you have to use a `float` or `double` type. Do note that these types are not as precise as you might think, so if you assign a value of 4.57 you might end up with an actual value of something like 4.569999999....

In your code, you'd want to change the type of `f` to a `float`, and you'd probably want to do a cast from integer to float on the items you're dividing to make sure they keep any floating point information.

So, your line of

```
int f = z/b;
```

would become

```
float f = (float)z/(float)b;
```

and then you'd use the `%.1f` in your `printf` as @BalogPal suggested.

Comment: Note that if `z` and `b` are already floats you do not need to cast them.

Comment: @user2527918 np, glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I am not "fluent" in C but I think you should use float instead of int.
A division of an integer by an integer will return an integer.

Note also that you should use %f instead of %d to display float in prinf

Your code should be :

```
//
//  main.c
//  cmd4
//
//  Created by Kevin Rudd on 27/06/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Charlie Brown. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  float x =10.0, y =20.0, b = 500.0;
  float z = x*y;
  float f = z/b;

  // insert code here...
  printf("x is:%f, y is:%f, b is %f\n",x,y,b);
  printf("x times y is: %f\n",z);
  printf("z divided by b is: %f\n",f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the "integer by integer will return an integer"  that makes sense now.  But float returns the 0.00000

Answer (score 0):

Integer division is defined that way. It just drops the remainder for 300/500 and leaves you with 0.

Comment: how would i use that in the above?

Comment: Appreciate the fact that this is probably as basic as it gets.  Sorry about the level of stupidity but thats what learning is I guess.  Thanks for the assist so far Balog.

Answer (score -1):

Because the integer division of a and b is 0 when a is less than b you know. You see C behaves differently from Python!

Comment: so should i be using something other than int?